# How does gdb implement call function

Tags: c, gdb, ptrace

When I use gdb to debug process in arm linux I can use call like `call write(123,"abc",3)`

How does gdb inject that call into process and recover all?

Comment: Consider how breakpoints work on Linux ARM devices.  The debugger has already broken the code execution at the break-point, so it's just a matter of marshaling the parameters in accordance with ARM ABI and calling the specified entry point.  The return value is usually in a register, gets converted for display and the debugger waits for you next instruction.

Comment: Way too broad of a question. See: https://github.com/eklitzke/ptrace-call-userspace

Comment: WIth GDB being an open source utility, Suggest reading the source, starting with: `https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/current/`  Then retrieve the source via: `git clone git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git`  and can install `git` via: `sudo apt install git`

Answer (score 2):

> How does gdb inject that call into process and recover all?

GDB can read and write the inferior (being debugged) process memory using [ptrace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) system call.

So it reads and saves in its own memory some chunk of instructions from inferior (say 100 bytes).

Then it overwrites this chunk with *new* instructions, which look something like:

```
r0 = 123
r1 = pointer to "abc"
r2 = 3
BLR write
BKPT
```

Now GDB saves the current inferior registers,  sets `ip` to point to the chunk of instructions it just wrote, and resumes the inferior.

Inferior executes instructions until it reaches the breakpoint, at which point GDB regains control. It can now look at the return register to know what `write` returned and print it. GDB now restores the original instructions and original register values, and we are back as if nothing happened.

P.S. This is a general description of how "call function in inferior" works; I do not claim that this is *exactly* how it works.

There are also complications: if `write` calls back into the code that GDB overwrote, it wouldn't work. So in reality GDB uses some other mechanism to obtain suitable "scratch area" in the inferior. Also, the `"abc"` string requires scratch area as well.